# How to force the modal bottom sheet to just take space as its inside children needed

Tags: flutter, dart

For whole app I need many modal bottom sheets so I created a basic modal bottom sheets which takes its child from outside.I don't want to explicitly specify the height of each child for each modal bottom sheets and I just want to be as high as the inside children need.

Comment: try setting `isScrollControlled` to true.

Comment: thanks for the question. Also add what you tried, where you got stuck. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask